# Loading an XML file given its URL into Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, url

I'm trying to load an XML file into an XMLTextReader using it's URL but I keep on getting the following error whenever I call the Read() method.

System.Net.WebException: 'The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF'.

The following snippet of code is generating the error.

```
string url = "https://someurl.xml";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
reader.Read();
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?